How to use MockK to unit test Android code that contains mutually recursive functions?
In my application code, FunctionA sometimes calls FunctionB and FunctionB in turn sometimes calls FunctionA. The recursion eventually always terminates when they reach a certain variables state.
When mocking such recursive functions using MockK in unit tests, is there a design pattern, methodology, or specific syntax used to prevent the error shown below:
Caused by: io.mockk.MockKException: every/verify {} block were run several times. Recorded calls count differ between runs
I've tried many potential solutions including annotating my mock objects with "@RelaxedMockK" and specifying "relaxUnitFun = true" and using the generic "any()" to replace all function arguments, but none resolve the issue so far.
